# Plotting a stacked bar plot?

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the following data:

```
structure(list(Time = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L), Type = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Value = c(848565.34, 
1463110.61, 626673.64, 277708.41, 841422.11, 956238.14, 461092.16, 
208703.75, 800837.48, 1356164.25, 549509.34, 300241.53, 851247.9714, 
1353358.318, 598536.5948, 307485.0918, 332042.2275, 666157.8721, 
194981.1566, 79344.50328, 831003.6952, 1111311.517, 521632.3074, 
274384.1731, 1174671.569, 1070301.745, 454876.1589, 351973.2418, 
5631710.101, 279394.6061, 119034.4969, 39693.31587, 1166869.32, 
1156855.09, 369816.8152, 274092.5751, 924474.1129, 975028.0207, 
449213.7419, 213855.3067, 1967188.317, 178841.604, 43692.69319, 
12493.90538, 835142.6168, 876273.4462, 354154.644, 182794.3813, 
1158096.251, 998647.6908, 566726.9865, 195099.4295, 1798902.332, 
171519.4741, 81644.02724, 12221.41779, 1301775.314, 920464.9992, 
294140.4882, 175626.9677, 2179780.499, 1838687.535, 978775.2674, 
366668.3462, 5385970.324, 177527.1577, 65310.32674, 5986.871716, 
2250834.171, 1547858.632, 666444.2992, 251767.3006, 1786086.335, 
1597055.451, 563976.9719, 309186.1626, 487105.824, 279712.1658, 
86471.46603, 24434.05486, 1563940.414, 1409428.038, 531425.682, 
257056.5524, 1685501.271, 1371943.438, 881348.5022, 313355.8284, 
170771.9118, 155596.7479, 59881.60825, 12090.57989, 1668571.543, 
1150257.058, 563054.758, 306767.0344, 2214849.859, 1724719.891, 
822092.2031, 443194.4609, 8897796.235, 87491.42925, 10699.30103, 
18131.89738, 2137240.993, 1476873.778, 741685.9913, 549539.9735, 
1362085.657, 1266106.09, 448653.8889, 278236.8416, 1671665.39, 
95239.07396, 54173.57043, 10125.82011, 1335200.152, 1167824.903, 
426738.1845, 261255.2092)), .Names = c("Time", "Type", "Value"
), row.names = c(NA, -120L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to plot a stacked bar graph that looks like this:

[image]

I know that adding `position="identity"` or `position="dodge"` produces different types of bar plots but am not sure how to produce the above chart with both types. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are the values split on each bar? I can imagine having it stacked by type or one bar for each type.

Comment: @Maiasaura: This is inside the output of `dput`. The values are in order i.e. for Type 1 on Day 1, there are four values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Time), y = Value, fill = factor(Type))) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "stack")
```

[image]

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Time), y = Value, fill = factor(Type))) + 
 geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

You can do one or the other but not both. When they are `dodged`, the different values of type are being used. By adding a color outline, you can see that.

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Time), y = Value, fill = factor(Type))) + 
 geom_bar(stat="identity", position = c("dodge"), colour = 'black')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I am missing something. Let's take an example. On day 1, I see only one value being used for Type 1. Where are the other values?