# ggplot2 - bar plot with both stack and dodge

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a barplot using `ggplot2` where I am stacking by one variable and dodging by another.

Here is an example data set:

```
df=data.frame(
  year=rep(c("2010","2011"),each=4),
  treatment=rep(c("Impact","Control")),
  type=rep(c("Phylum1","Phylum2"),each=2),
  total=sample(1:100,8))
```

I would like to create a barplot where `x=treatment`, `y=total`, the stacked variable is `type` and the dodged variable is `year`. Of course I can do one or the other:

```
ggplot(df,aes(y=total,x=treatment,fill=type))+geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")

ggplot(df,aes(y=total,x=treatment,fill=year))+geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")
```

But not both! Thanks to anyone who can provide advice.

Comment: You can only do one or the other, not both. See my related answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592041/plotting-a-stacked-bar-plot/12592235#12592235

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's an alternative take using faceting instead of dodging:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = total, fill = type)) +
    geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
    facet_wrap( ~ treatment)
```

[image]

With Tyler's suggested change: `+ theme(panel.margin = grid::unit(-1.25, "lines"))`

[image]

Comment: Good alternative to wanting both. +1

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea. I guess it will have to do!  Thanks to both @Maiasaura and Matt Parker

Comment: adding `+ theme(panel.margin = unit(-1.25, "lines"))` can kind of make them more look like they're in the same visual field but still not exactly what the OP was after.  Nice best alternative. +1

Comment: @TylerRinker Nice - didn't even know such a thing was possible! Just a tip for anyone who follows: I had to use `grid::unit` to get this without loading `grid` directly.

Comment: This does not answer the question. How could it be the accpeted answer ?

Comment: @Julien Most of the answers on this question were posted more than five years after the question was asked, and the question-asker hasn't been active for three years. It's a limitation of StackOverflow. If you prefer a different answer, you should comment on that one and say something like, "This is the best answer for the original question."

Comment: How can I say  "This is the best answer for the original question." if it does not answer the original question?

Comment: How can I horizontally shift the position of the bars so each facet will have adjacent bars?

Comment: @arielhasidim Do you mean having the 2010 bars next to each other, then the 2011 bars? In that case, I think you'd just swap `year` and `treatment` in the code above.

Answer (score 12):

The closest you can get is by drawing a border around the `dodged` bars to highlight the stacked `type` values.

```
ggplot(df, aes(treatment, total, fill = year)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", color="black")
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, the borders don't appear to line up with the data. For example, `set.seed(8)` before running the code and look at the values.

Comment: If you really wanted to get fancy I bet you could use `geom_rect` to fill in some parts but then you're using ggplot to draw rather than plot.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `interaction(year, treatment)` as the x-axis variable as an alternative to `dodge`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


df=data.frame(
  year=rep(c("2010","2011"),each=4),
  treatment=rep(c("Impact","Control")),
  type=rep(c("Phylum1","Phylum2"),each=2),
  total=sample(1:100,8)) %>% 
  mutate(x_label = factor(str_replace(interaction(year, treatment), '\\.', ' / '),
                          ordered=TRUE))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x_label, y=total, fill=type)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  labs(x='Year / Treatment')
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-26 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: interaction seemed only was used to create labels? Then why not just `paste0(year, "/", treatment)`?

Answer (score 9):

you can play with some alpha:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(year, treatment) %>% 
  mutate(cum_tot = cumsum(total)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(treatment, cum_tot, fill =year)) + 
  geom_col(data = . %>% filter( type=="Phylum1"), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), alpha = 1) +
  geom_col(data = . %>% filter( type=="Phylum2"), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_tile(aes(y=NA_integer_, alpha = factor(type))) + 
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1,0.4))
```

[image]

Now you can add `theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill  ="yellow"))` some background fill to mix the colors:

[image]

Finally you have to fix the legend using inkscape.

Answer (score 5):

It can be done however its tricky/fiddly, you basically have to layer the bar chart.

here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df=data.frame(
  year=rep(c(2010,2011),each=4),
  treatment=rep(c("Impact","Control")),
  type=rep(c("Phylum1","Phylum2"),each=2),
  total=sample(1:100,8))

# separate the by the variable which we are dodging by so 
# we have two data frames impact and control
impact <- df %>% filter(treatment == "Impact") %>% 
  mutate(pos = sum(total, na.rm=T))

control <- df %>% filter(treatment == "Control") %>% 
  mutate(pos = sum(total, na.rm=T))

# calculate the position for the annotation element
impact_an <- impact %>% group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(
    pos = sum(total) + 12
    , treatment = first(treatment)
  )

control_an <- control %>% group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(
    pos = sum(total) + 12
    , treatment = first(treatment)
  )

# define the width of the bars, we need this set so that
# we can use it to position the second layer geom_bar 
barwidth = 0.30

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(
    data = impact
    , aes(x = year, y = total, fill = type)
    , position = "stack"
    , stat = "identity"
    , width = barwidth
  ) + 
  annotate(
    "text"
    , x = impact_an$year
    ,y = impact_an$pos
    , angle = 90
    , label = impact_an$treatment
  ) +
  geom_bar(
    data = control
    # here we are offsetting the position of the second layer bar
    # by adding the barwidth plus 0.1 to push it to the right
    , aes(x = year + barwidth + 0.1, y = total, fill = type)
    , position = "stack"
    , stat = "identity"
    , width = barwidth
  ) +
  annotate(
    "text"
    , x = control_an$year + (barwidth * 1) + 0.1
    ,y = control_an$pos
    , angle = 90
    , label = control_an$treatment
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c(2010, 2011))
```

[image: stacked dodged barchar]
This doesn't really scale well, however there are ways you could code it up to make it suit your situation, credit where its due I originally learnt this method from the following post: https://community.rstudio.com/t/ggplot-position-dodge-with-position-stack/16425

Comment: I tried something similar, but instead of manually calculating the bar position, you can actually put every layer in a separate set of discrete x axis values, like 2010-a (for impact), 2010-b (for control), 2010-gap (as white space), then override the axis labels. This way you only need to manipulate your data a little bit then draw each layer on each own x values.

Answer (score 0):

It's immensely hacky and time consuming, and so suitable only for a chart that you really care about, but you can annotate a plot with rectangles to produce the desired effect. First, you have to work out (by trial and error) where ggplot is placing each dodged bar's centre point (a manual process, but for factor variables it's not too painful). When you have that and the relevant maximum and minimum values (derived from the underlying plot) creating a df with the relevant rectangle coordinates and placing it over the plot (with a suitable alpha) seems to work. In the image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk7jm.png), the orange bars have been partly covered by white rectangles with alpha 0.6, to de-emphasise them. The effect is quite nice IMO.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).