# making a stacked bar graph with 3 bars for each category

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
      Marker   Method NAtype        Ratio
1     CSF1PO      GEL     -9 3.623417e-01
2     CSF1PO      GEL     -1 4.713273e-02
3     CSF1PO      GEL     NA 0.000000e+00
4     CSF1PO MegaBACE     -9 1.417205e-02
5     CSF1PO MegaBACE     -1 8.312974e-03
6     CSF1PO MegaBACE     NA 5.405026e-06
7     CSF1PO      ABI     -9 4.714592e-02
8     CSF1PO      ABI     -1 1.989925e-03
9     CSF1PO      ABI     NA 4.174494e-05
10  D10S1248      GEL     -9 9.999201e-01
11  D10S1248      GEL     -1 7.098303e-05
12  D10S1248      GEL     NA 0.000000e+00
13  D10S1248 MegaBACE     -9 6.562637e-01
14  D10S1248 MegaBACE     -1 2.518769e-03
15  D10S1248 MegaBACE     NA 1.081005e-05
16  D10S1248      ABI     -9 7.138484e-03
17  D10S1248      ABI     -1 1.029723e-03
18  D10S1248      ABI     NA 1.391498e-05
```

I want to make a stacked bar graph with these data. I'm not fluent in ggplot2 and I don't know how to create 3 bars for each category.

For example, the 1st column has my categories, these are the names that go in the x axis of my graph. For each category ("CSF1PO" and "D10S1248"), I want 3 bars ("GEL", "MegaBACE", "ABI" in the 2nd column). Each bar should be divided in 3 subsets ("-9", "-1", "NA" in the 3rd column). And the 4th column (Ratio) has my values.

I want something like

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Marker, y=Ratio, fill=NAtype)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid(~Method)
```

but with the bars for each category side-by-side, not in separated grids.
Can anyone help please?
Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to both dodge and stack the bars, I don't [believe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12715635/3243640) you can.

Answer (score 2):

`ggplot2` does not allow you to include both `stack` and `dodge` as positions in the same plot. But you can achieve what you want by using `facet_wrap`. See this example with your data:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Method, Ratio, fill = Method)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", postion = "dodge") + facet_wrap(~Marker)
```

[image]

Comment: that's interesting. Thanks! But now I don't have the subsets of my data (df$NAtype) plotted... they should be the stacks in the bars. So it's not possible to do that?