# Make a stacked bar plot with many groups in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am a R user which have changed to Python. But I find matplotlib to be very diffcult to use. In the following post:

[ggplot2 - bar plot with both stack and dodge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715635/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-both-stack-and-dodge)

The first answer makes this plot in R:

[image: Stacked with group]

I have managed to make a bar plot when I have one group. But how to I do two groups like that?

Comment: Look up [subplots](https://www.google.com/#q=matplotlib+subplot).

Comment: someone wrote this https://github.com/yhat/ggplot