# Position dodge for aes fill and position stack for aes color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot this data frame with a barplot :

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(c("x1", "x2"), each = 4L), 
                 f = rep(c("f1", "f2"), each = 2L, times = 2L),
                 c = rep(c("c1", "c2"), 4L),
                 y = c(rbind(seq(0.1, 0.4, by = 0.1), 1 - seq(0.1, 0.4, by = 0.1))))
```

I would like to dodge the bars for distinct fill values but also keep them  stacked for the same fill values, when it's just the color value which is different.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, 
               y = y, 
               fill = f, 
               color = c)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

So in this case all bars would be stacked to 1 with distinct "color" in it.

Do you have any idea on how I can achieve this ? I would like to avoid faceting.

Thank You !

Comment: maybe adding `group = f` to `aes`?

Comment: Like so `ggplot(df, aes(interaction(x, f), y, value, fill = c)) + geom_col()` ?

Comment: Relevant: [ggplot2 - bar plot with both stack and dodge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715635/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-both-stack-and-dodge)

Comment: @markus I saw this thread but I ideally don't want to use `interaction` to mofidy my x values

Comment: @amatsuo_net how would you use the aes(group = f), I can't make it work on my side

Comment: Can you elaborate on *why* you'd want to avoid both `facet_*` & `interaction()`?