# Showing a subgroup or subdivision within a histogram bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have data as follows:

```
thevalues <- structure(c(9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 6, 4, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 7, 7, 9, 
8, 8, 9, 5, 5, 8, 7, 5, 9, 9, 7, 7, 9, 8, 7, 8, 9, 4, 7, 9, 8, 
6, 7, 7, 4, 8, 6, 9, 9, 8, 1, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 9, 6, 7, 4, 7, 9, 
6, 6, 9, 9, 8, 6, 8, 7, 7, 7, 5, 9, 5, 7, 9, 8, 4, 9, 8, 8, 8, 
5, 8, 1, 7, 7, 5, 6, 9, 5, 9, 6, 9, 6, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
4, 6, 4, 8, 6, 8, 8, 7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 8, 8, 8, 7, 9, 3, 8, 8, 6, 
9, 8, 8, 6, 5, 8, 3, 8, 6, 8, 7, 7, 6, 9, 5, 9, 8, 7, 9, 7, 9, 
9, 8, 9, 6, 8, 9, 8, 6, 8, 9, 9, 9, 4, 8, 8, 5, 8, 7, 8, 8, 9, 
9, 6, 8, 5, 9, 8, 7, 9, 9, 7, 6, 8, 7, 7, 8, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 
6, 6, 9, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 2, 4, 9, 9, 7, 7, 9, 7, 6, 9, 9, 8, 5, 
5), label = NA_character_, class = c("labelled", "numeric"))

mistakes <- structure(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0), label = NA_character_, class = c("labelled", "numeric"))
```

I want to create a histogram of `thevalues` like so:

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(A), 
                 variable = rep(c("thevalues"), each = length(A)))

ggplot(df, aes(value, fill = variable)) +
    geom_density(aes(y = ..count..), size = 0.7, alpha = 0.1) +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge") + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:9), labels = c(1:9)) + 
    theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = c(0.1, 0.85))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

However, I would like to see the `mistakes` as part of these bars:

```
table(thevalues, mistakes)

         mistakes
thevalues  0  1
        1  1  1
        2  1  0
        3  1  1
        4  9  2
        5 10  4
        6 17  8 # The total height of the bar is 25, 8 have a different colour.
        7 24 16 # The total height of the bar is 40, 16 have a different colour.
        8 33 16 # The total height of the bar is 49, 16 have a different colour.
        9 49 14 # The total height of the bar is 63, 14 have a different colour.
```

Something like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

EDIT:

The solution works perfectly, but I would really like to do this when there are two variables in the histogram:

```
thevalues_II <- structure(c(9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 6, 9, 8, 8, 6, 9, 9, 9, 6, 7, 9, 
7, 8, 9, 7, 9, 9, 8, 7, 9, 8, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 7, 
8, 9, 7, 7, 8, 4, 6, 9, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9, 4, 8, 9, 
8, 7, 9, 9, 8, 7, 8, 9, 8, 2, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 4, 9, 9, 8, 
3, 7, 3, 8, 8, 9, 7, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
7, 3, 7, 9, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 6, 9, 9, 6, 7, 8, 7, 
8, 9, 9, 7, 6, 8, 7, 9, 6, 5, 8, 8, 7, 9, 8, 9, 9, 7, 9, 7, 9, 
8, 7, 9, 4, 8, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 4, 9, 9, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
8, 9, 5, 9, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 
7, 4, 8, 7, 7, 9, 8, 8, 7, 5, 8, 9, 8, 8, 9, 8, 5, 8, 9, 8, 9, 
7), label = NA_character_, class = c("labelled", "numeric"))

df <- data.frame(value = c(thevalues, thevalues_II), 
                 variable = rep(c("tax", "truth"), each = length(A)))

ggplot(df, aes(value, fill = variable)) +
    geom_density(aes(y = ..count..), size = 0.7, alpha = 0.3) +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge") + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
    theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = c(0.1, 0.85))
```

[image]

I tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf <- data.frame(thevalues, mistakes)

mycount <- count(mydf, thevalues, thevalues_II, mistakes)

ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = mycount, aes(thevalues, thevalues_II, n, fill = as.character(mistakes))) +
  geom_density(data = mydf, aes(thevalues, thevalues_II, y = ..count..), size = 0.7, alpha = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = c(0.1, 0.85))
```

But that does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a summarising count first. Apologies again for lack of image - using online console with reduced facilities.

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf <- data.frame(thevalues, mistakes)

mycount <- count(mydf, thevalues, mistakes)

ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = mycount, aes(thevalues, n, fill = as.character(mistakes))) +
  geom_density(data = mydf, aes(thevalues, y = ..count..), size = 0.7, alpha = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = c(0.1, 0.85))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will delete the other question.

Comment: Okay, now I cannot figure out how to add another variable. I am so bad at this. As you might remember from the very poorly written earlier question I wanted to do this when apart from `thevalues` there are more values let's say, `thevalues_II`. Is there any easy way to add this (I will make an edit)?

Comment: @Tom you're looking for "dodge and stack at the same time". this is currently difficult - and I find in terms of visualisation also maybe confusing. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715635/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-both-stack-and-dodge for workarounds

Comment: I have another idea in that case.. I think I can just subtract the penalty count from the other counts, and then sum them instead in the plot, or would that still be "dodge and stack at the same time"?

Comment: I keep on circling the solution.. Now I have both (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65955368/making-a-bar-plot-with-stack-and-dodge), but I cannot figure out how to get the other options back..