# I would like to combine a stacked and grouped barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have only one time 'timepoint 0-1-2' with group 1 and 2 along each other per timepoint.
In my graph group 1 and two are completely separated.

I am using the following code

```
ggplot(data2, aes(x = Timepoint, y = percentage_of_patients_CTCAE_1, fill = CTCAE_1)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +facet_grid(~ Group)
```

[image]

this is the data I am using

structure(
list(
Group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
1, 1, 1),
Timepoint = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0,
1, 2),
CTCAE_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,
2),
percentage_of_patients_CTCAE_1 = c(
86.6666666666667,
66.6666666666667,
33.3333333333333,
86.6666666666667,
73.3333333333333,
73.3333333333333,
6.66666666666667,
20,
33.3333333333333,
6.66666666666667,
20,
13.3333333333333,
6.66666666666667,
6.66666666666667,
33.3333333333333
)
),
row.names = c(NA,-15L),
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Facet by `Timepoint` and map `Group` on `x`. For this and other options see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12715768/12993861 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/21410145/12993861 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65955368/making-a-bar-plot-with-stack-and-dodge-and-keep-the-dodged-bars-touching-one-an

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?