# ggplot barplot: 2-dimensional x-axis with colored bars based on category

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Is it possible to create a barplot using ggplot, where 2 attributes are represented on the x-axis? In addition I would like to fill the bars with colors based on a category.

The problem is pictured [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLFR6.jpg). Every row in the table represents a season of a certain player. I want to make graph that shows the performance (stat) of each player in each year (season). The colors of the bars should represent the league, in which the player has played in that particular season.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Season, y=Stat, fill=League)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. Can you provide us with some example data and code of your attempts to visualise this, as well as a description of where you got stuck?

Comment: The following code creates a plot with the Season on the x-axis, however I would like to include the Season as well as the Player on the x-axis (just like in the picture above): ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x=Season, y=Stat, fill=League)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715635/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-both-stack-and-dodge - plenty of good advice.

Comment: PS this also contains the facet option which you might want to have a real close look at

Answer (score 3):

Here are two options. The first is by labelling the years with text:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  Player = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3),
  Season = rep(c(2016, 2017, 2018), 3),
  Leage = c("Premier Leage", "Bundesliga")[c(1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2)],
  Stat = c(0.65, 0.7, 0.97, 0.85, 0.59, 0.78, 0.93, 0.86, 0.44)
)

ggplot(df, aes(Player, Stat, fill = Leage, group = Season)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), width = 0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Season, y = 0),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),
            vjust = 1.5)
```

[image]

And the second is having the outer labels by facets.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Season, Stat, fill = Leage)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ Player, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>