# How to plot a stacked and grouped bar plot in rstudio?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I already created a grouped barchart, that shows the number of clients (n=25) grouped by agegroup and gender. But now I need to include all clients (n=52) that were screened for the study to show quality of data. It should look like the attached barchart, but with the total number stacked in a lighter color, so one can see: In Age Group 1, we screened for example 15 females and 9 males, but in the end only 8 females signed up for the study. I hope it is understandable like this. I'll add the existing bar chart.

the code for this chart is the following:
[image]

```
ggplot(data=daten, aes(x=AG, y=stat(count), group=factor(GESCHLECHT), fill=factor(GESCHLECHT)))+
        geom_bar(position=position_dodge2(preserve="single", padding=0))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("steelblue","darkred"), labels=c("Männlich", "Weiblich"))+
  labs(y="Anzahl", x="Altersgruppen", fill="Geschlecht:")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,3, by=1), labels=c("25 bis <51","51 bis <65", ">65"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 10))+
  geom_text(aes(label=stat(count)),stat="count", vjust=-0.5, position=position_dodge(width = 1))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

I have no idea how to organize my data so that I could do something like that. In the end it should look like that above the first bar (n=8) the bar should continue, only with for example a lighter color and then lets say with n=6 more females (in the end that would show that we screened 15 females in total in that agegroup)

I think first I would need to create a data frame with all n=52 clients, with a code for Age Group and gender. But how can I divide the bars so that the difference between screened and recruited clients become clear?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
# example data
n <- 100
data <- tibble(
  gender = sample(c("m", "f"), n, replace = TRUE),
  age = runif(n, 25, 70) %>% as.integer(),
  screened = rep(TRUE, 0.8 * n) %>% c(rep(FALSE, 0.2 * n)) %>% sample()
)
data
#> # A tibble: 100 × 3
#>    gender   age screened
#>    <chr>  <int> <lgl>   
#>  1 m         54 TRUE    
#>  2 f         40 FALSE   
#>  3 m         37 FALSE   
#>  4 m         69 TRUE    
#>  5 f         53 TRUE    
#>  6 m         34 TRUE    
#>  7 m         30 TRUE    
#>  8 m         46 TRUE    
#>  9 f         66 TRUE    
#> 10 f         51 TRUE    
#> # … with 90 more rows

data %>%
  mutate(
    age_group = age %>% cut(breaks = c(0, 25, 51, 65, Inf))
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = age_group, fill = gender, alpha = screened)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(`TRUE` = 1, `FALSE` = 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and your help! It looks almost like I pictured it, but it would be great if the bars for male and female were side by side like in the original plot. Do you maybe have an idea how to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715635/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-both-stack-and-dodge