# How to dodge and stack a bar plot with a pattern in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpattern

I have a dataframe in R which is as below :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggraph)
library(scales)
library(ggpattern)

df <- structure(list(Category_A = c("Class_A", "Class_A", "Class_A", 
"Class_A", "Class_A", "Class_A", "Class_C", "Class_C", "Class_C", 
"Class_C", "Class_C", "Class_C", "Class_B", "Class_B", "Class_B", 
"Class_B", "Class_B", "Class_B"), Category_B = c("Class_A", "Class_A", 
"Class_C", "Class_C", "Class_B", "Class_B", "Class_A", "Class_A", 
"Class_C", "Class_C", "Class_B", "Class_B", "Class_A", "Class_A", 
"Class_C", "Class_C", "Class_B", "Class_B"), Score = c("Fail", 
"Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Pass"), count = c(19837.25, 156448.75, 134.5, 1105.75, 33738, 
162531, 322.75, 2134.5, 190.25, 2119.25, 1514, 8450.25, 139259, 
549000.5, 1419.75, 7180, 37118.25, 231676)), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), groups = structure(list(Category_A = c("Class_A", "Class_A", 
"Class_A", "Class_B", "Class_B", "Class_B", "Class_C", "Class_C", 
"Class_C"), Category_B = c("Class_A", "Class_B", "Class_C", "Class_A", 
"Class_B", "Class_C", "Class_A", "Class_B", "Class_C"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:2, 5:6, 3:4, 13:14, 17:18, 15:16, 7:8, 11:12, 9:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am plotting it using the following code :

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill=Category_B, y=count, x=Category_A, pattern=Score)) + 
  geom_bar_pattern( position="dodge", stat="identity", pattern_spacing = 0.01,
                    pattern_frequency = 5, pattern_angle = 45)+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(y = "Count", x="")+
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("cyan3","darkgoldenrod1","brown2")) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values=c('stripe', 'none'))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = c("none", "none", "none")))) +
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm"), legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.background = element_rect(color = "transparent"), legend.position = "right",
        legend.direction = "vertical", legend.spacing.y = unit(0.4, 'cm'),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size=16))
```

And this is what I get

[image]

Upon changing `position="stack"`, this is what I get :
[image]

I would like it to be something like this though; where we have only three bars and they are highlighted by "Score" pattern.

[image]

Any solutions please?

Comment: Can you add the library calls to ggpattern and scales? I would edit but the que is full. Also I'm not familiar with the package but does setting `position='stack'` achieve what you want?

Comment: As a last resort, you might want to try faceting by `Category_A`

Comment: @dandrews thank you for replying. I added the libraries, and I added additional figure what "stack" would achieve.

Comment: @DmitryZotikov I would try avoiding faceting at the moment :( but if its not possible, then I'll try it.

Comment: I think I understand now, you want to use the "dodge" position for `Category_A` and the "stack" position for `Category_B` right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715635/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-both-stack-and-dodge an option with faceting as suggested

Comment: Final thought, perhaps it would be possible to summarise your data and add another geom layer and use transparency to achieve the desired results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP's question has more to do with wanting to *dodge and stack at the same time* with two different values in the dataset than it does specifically to do with using `ggpattern`.  With that said, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715635/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-both-stack-and-dodge) might be quite helpful with some options.

Simply put - there is no way to both set `position="dodge"` and `position="stack"` at the same time right out of the box.  The simplest way to approximate this behavior is to be creative in how you use **faceting**.

Here I'll show a solution which separates out `Category_A` into facets, which means we actually set `Category_B` as the x axis variable.  We keep `fill=Category_B` and remove the actual x axis labels, and use the facet labels to act as our x axis labels.  Here's the code, the resulting plot, and a brief explanation.  I've made a bunch of edits and added comments to OP's original plot code to help identify what the changes are doing and why.

#### The Code

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill=Category_B, y=count, x=Category_B, pattern=Score)) + 
  geom_col_pattern(
    position="stack",
    pattern_spacing = 0.02,  # had to fiddle to look right
    pattern_frequency = 5,
    pattern_fill=NA,   # removes gray parts you see between pattern lines
    pattern_angle = 45,
    color='white', linewidth=1   # white lines between stacked bars
  ) +
  theme_bw()+
  
  # add facets and push facet labels to the bottom
  facet_grid(.~Category_A, switch = "x") +
  
  labs(y = "Count", x="")+
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)),
                expand = expansion(mult=c(0, 0.05))  # removes space at bottom
  ) +
  
  # adds some space on the x axis between Category_B values
  scale_x_discrete(expand=expansion(mult=0.6)) +  # adds space between Category_B
  
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("cyan3","darkgoldenrod1","brown2")) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values=c('stripe', 'none'))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = c("none", "none", "none")))) +
  
  # format changes noted
  theme(
    legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm"), legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.background = element_rect(color = "transparent"), legend.position = "right",
    legend.direction = "vertical", legend.spacing.y = unit(0.4, 'cm'),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_rect(color=NA),  # remove the border around facets
    panel.spacing = unit(0, 'pt'),  # smoosh facets together
    strip.background = element_rect(color=NA, fill=NA),  # facet label format
    strip.placement = "outside", # get those facet labels outside the axis!
    axis.line = element_line(),  # add back in the axis lines
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),  # removes x axis labels
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), # removes x axis ticks
    text = element_text(size=16)
  )
```

#### The Plot

[image]

#### The Explanation

- **Changes to pattern geom**: I changed to `geom_col_pattern()` to remove the need for `stat="identity"`.  Most of the changes here are fiddling with the pattern arguments to make the pattern look right.
- **Adding white spaces**: To add the white space between the stacked bars, we set `linewidth` and `color=white` within `geom_col_pattern()`.  This draws a "white box" around each of the bars... therefore creating the illusion of space between the stacked bars.
- **Facets**: I use `facet_grid()` to make the facets and set the property of `switch="x"`, which makes the facet labels appear at the bottom of each facet (not the top, which is default).
- **Expanding axes**: I use `expand=` within `scale_x_log10()` to ensure the bottom of the bars sit on the axis (no white space).  I similarly use `scale_x_discrete(expand=...)`, but the purpose of this term is to *add* whitespace to the sides of each facet.  This allows us to separate the facets a bit without actually separating them... (more on that below)
- **Panel spacing**: In concert with the note above, we put the panels next to each other with `panel.spacing=unit(0, 'pt')`.  If we did not add the `scale_x_discrete(..)` term above, then we would have the bars too close between facets.  This ensures we can have a single x axis line, but separate the stuff in the facet by setting the whitespace in between (hope this makes sense).
- **Lines and stuff in theme**: There's a whole lot of `theme` stuff going on.  Basically, we remove the default x axis labels and tick marks, remove the background and format for the facet labels, we put the labels *outside the axis* with the `strip.position` term, we remove the default facet border and add back in the axis lines.

*Note: OP shows originally a chart where all bars go to the top of the screen.  If that is indeed the case, then OP would want to change `position="stack"` to read `position="fill"`.  If that change is met, the y axis labels wouldn't really mean much - might want to change to represent proportion using the `scales` package if needed.*

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfectly explained.

Answer (score 3):

I use ggplot geom_bar but it's simple and beautiful.
let's see:

```
df$Category_A <- as.factor(df$Category_A)
df$Category_B <- as.factor(df$Category_B)
df$Score <- as.factor(df$Score)
str(df)

ggplot(df, aes(fill=Category_B, x = Category_B, y = count, alpha = Score)) +
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(.~Category_A) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("cyan3","darkgoldenrod1","brown2")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.6,1)) +
  xlab("")+
  ylab("")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank(), 
        strip.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image: your desired plot]

you can also delete legend if you want

Comment: you can use `color = "white" , lwd = 1.5 ` into `geom_bar()` to have a line around your bars