# ggplot barplot with stacked numbers, positioned by one variable and colored by another

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking to have the following plot separately positioned by `Group`, on each level of values of Species:

```r
set.seed(101); x <- cbind( iris, Group = sample(LETTERS[1:3],size=nrow(iris),replace=TRUE))
ggplot(x) + geom_col( aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Width, fill=Group), col=1)
```

I added an crude illustration of what I want to achieve with the first Species, in the picture below:

[image: amateurish illustration]

Comment: It seems that you just need to add `position = position_dodge()` inside `geom_col`?

Comment: To me if I do that, the y value is way off, from expected around 50, as shown in my hackish figure, down to only around 4. I suspect all individual elements, every single red, blue and green brick from each stack, are then positioned in front of each other.

Comment: This seems a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/12715635/3358272, are you open to faceting? Something like `ggplot(x) + geom_col( aes(x=Group, y=Sepal.Width, fill=Group), color=1) + facet_grid(~ Species, switch = "both") + labs(x = "Species / Group")`

Comment: Worst case I'd have to resort to that. I was mainly surprised that something conceptually quite simple turned out to be so hard.

Comment: Add `width=1.5` to your geom_col for a ... surprisingly bad rendition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already suggested by @r2evans in his comment one option to fake dodging and stacking in the same chart would be to use the "facets that do not look like facets" trick, which means to facet by `Species` and to map `Group` on `x`. Additionally, to achieve the overlap of the stacked bars for the three groups one could set the `width` of the bars to a value > 1, which also requires to adjust the limits (which I do via `coord_cartesian`) and to arrange your data by `Group`. Finally, we have to do some adjustments via `theme()` to get rid of the facet look.

```r
set.seed(101)

x <- cbind(iris,
  Group = sample(LETTERS[1:3], size = nrow(iris), replace = TRUE)
)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

x |>
  dplyr::arrange(Species, Group) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(
    aes(x = Group, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Group),
    col = 1, width = 1.5
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = "B") +
  facet_wrap(~Species, scales = "free_x", strip.position = "bottom") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(.55, 3.45)) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    strip.background.x = element_blank(),
    panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "pt"),
    strip.placement = "outside"
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL)
#> Warning: `position_stack()` requires non-overlapping x intervals
#> `position_stack()` requires non-overlapping x intervals
#> `position_stack()` requires non-overlapping x intervals
```

[image]

Comment: TIL `panel.spacing=unit(0,"pt")` and `strip.placement="outside"`, thanks!