# Is it possible to have a side by side bar chart but "stacked" with shading in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a bar chart showing spending by Fiscal Year side by side. That seems pretty easy to do. However, what I cannot figure out is how to add shading to each bar to denote whether the money was appropriated or requested. Below is my following attempt at the code and it ends up making appropriated vs. requested a separate bar. I want them on the same bar, but shaded darker/lighter based on what they are categorized as. Any help is always appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)


project_data <- tibble(
  Project_Name = rep("Project A", 8),
  Budget_Year = c("2020_Budget","2020_Budget","2020_Budget","2020_Budget",
                  "2021_Budget","2021_Budget","2021_Budget","2021_Budget"),
  Fiscal_Year = c("2020", "2020", "2021", "2021", "2020", "2020", "2021", "2021"),
  Funding_Type = c("Appropriated", "Requested", "Appropriated", "Requested",
                   "Appropriated", "Requested", "Appropriated", "Requested"),
  Funding = runif(8, min = 1000000, max = 5000000)  
)


project_plot <- ggplot(project_data, aes(x = Fiscal_Year,
                                                    y = Funding,
                                                    fill = Budget_Year,
                                                    alpha = Funding_Type)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar) +
  labs(title = "Funding for Project A Over Time",
       x = "Fiscal Year",
       y = "Total Project Funding") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 18),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 18),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 16),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "grey"))


project_plot
```

Comment: It's probably more readable if you add a `scale_alpha` to the plot to change the transparency to values set explicitly to the levels you want.

Comment: For example `project_plot + scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 0.5))`. Also change `position = "dodge"` to `position = "stack"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at this - I've tried to improve some readability and style
throughout and did some tweaking in the code where the comments are. @qdread
did a good job explaining some basic functions to get you started, this is just my implementation of them.

```
base::library(package = ggplot2)
base::library(package = scales)
base::library(package = tibble)

project_data <- tibble(
  Project_Name = rep("Project A", 8),
  Budget_Year  = c(
    rep("2020_Budget", times = 4),
    rep("2021_Budget", times = 4)
  ),
  Fiscal_Year  = rep(c("2020", "2020", "2021", "2021"), 2),
  Funding_Type = rep(c("Appropriated", "Requested"), 4),
  Funding      = runif(8, min = 1000000, max = 5000000)
)

project_plot <- ggplot(
  data    = project_data,
  mapping = aes(
    x     = Fiscal_Year,
    y     = Funding,
    fill  = Budget_Year,
    alpha = Funding_Type
  )
) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") + # Putting both funding types on same bar
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar) +
  # Adjusting alpha values for transparency
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 0.3)) +
  # Fixing legend labels
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("2020 Budget", "2021 Budget")) +
  labs(
    title = "Funding for Project A Over Time",
    x     = "Fiscal Year",
    y     = "Total Project Funding",
    # Fixing legend titles
    fill  = "Budget Year",
    alpha = "Funding Type"
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    plot.title         = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20),
    axis.title.x       = element_text(size = 18),
    axis.title.y       = element_text(size = 18),
    axis.text.x        = element_text(size = 14),
    axis.text.y        = element_text(size = 14),
    legend.text        = element_text(size = 14),
    legend.title       = element_text(size = 16),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "grey")
  )

print(project_plot)
```

Take a look at the output and let me know if these are the adjustments you were thinking of. Keep in mind that your running of the code may look very different because of how the function `runif()` randomizes data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

everyone. It looks like someone already had this kind of question, but my Googling skills weren't great.

Here is what I was looking for: [ggplot2 - bar plot with both stack and dodge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715635/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-both-stack-and-dodge)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(year, treatment) %>% 
  mutate(cum_tot = cumsum(total)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(treatment, cum_tot, fill =year)) + 
  geom_col(data = . %>% filter( type=="Phylum1"), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), alpha = 1) +
  geom_col(data = . %>% filter( type=="Phylum2"), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_tile(aes(y=NA_integer_, alpha = factor(type))) + 
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1,0.4))
```