# All the bars are falsely the same hight in a bar plot

Tags: r, tidyverse

What goes wrong in this code? The bars should absolutely not be the same hight. Otherwise, the plot looks correct showing comparison between two age groups on a numeric variable on the y-axis.

This is the code I used

```
# Add a new column to indicate age group
young$age_group <- "Young"
old$age_group <- "Old"

# Combine the data frames
combined_df <- bind_rows(young, old)

# Plot
ggplot(combined_df, aes(x = age_group, y = implvdm, fill = gndr)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  labs(x = "Age Group", y = "implvdm", fill = "Gender") +
  theme_minimal()
```

The code creates this plot

[image]

Data for the plot is

```
young <- structure(list(gndr = c("woman", "man", "man", "man", "woman", 
"man", "man", "woman", "woman", "man"), yrbrn = c(2003L, 1999L, 
1998L, 1999L, 2002L, 1999L, 2001L, 2004L, 2004L, 1999L), agea = c(18L, 
22L, 23L, 22L, 19L, 22L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 22L), impdema = c(6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), implvdm = c(10L, 7L, 9L, 
7L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 10L), accalaw = c(0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L), imwbcnt = c(9L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 0L, 10L, 
2L, 3L, 7L, 6L), euftf = c(4L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 
9L), freehms = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), gincdif = c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L), prtclffi = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

old <- structure(list(gndr = c("man", "woman", "woman", "man", "woman", 
"man", "woman", "woman", "woman", "woman"), yrbrn = c(1943L, 
1975L, 1974L, 1977L, 1959L, 1993L, 1990L, 1993L, 1958L, 1971L
), agea = c(78L, 46L, 47L, 44L, 63L, 27L, 31L, 29L, 63L, 50L), 
    impdema = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 1L), implvdm = c(10L, 
    9L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 10L), accalaw = c(0L, 8L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 0L), imwbcnt = c(9L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 7L), euftf = c(8L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
    3L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 5L), freehms = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    4L, 2L, 4L, 1L), gincdif = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L), prtclffi = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Note, that I don't want stacked bars like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715635/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-both-stack-and-dodge).

Comment: It sounds like you want ggplot to both stack and dodge your values. As is, you are just dodging, so all the bars are overlapping and you only see the ones that are 10 high. (Test by setting `alpha = 0.2` on your bars.) I think this question offers some solutions for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715635/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-both-stack-and-dodge

Comment: `geom_bar` "counts" cases.  `geom_col` summarises values.  You have 10 cases (rows) in each of your data frames, twenty in total.  `geom_bar` is working as expected.

Comment: ^ Except setting `stat = "identity"` converts `geom_bar` to the behavior of `geom_col`, so it is plotting the values of `implvdm`. It just looks wrong b/c overlapped.