# R bar plot both stacked and dodged with non-numeric x

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the following code (sorry for it being partly in danish)

```
produkt_A_data <- Kompletdatasæt %>% 
  filter(Produkt == "A") %>%
  group_by(Grundlag) %>%
  summarise(Bidrag = sum(Bidrag*PVpræmie), Depot = sum(Depot), GaranteretYdelse = sum(GaranteretYdelse*PVydelse))

# Convert data to long format for plotting
produkt_A_data_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(produkt_A_data, cols = -Grundlag, names_to = "Attribute", values_to = "Value")

# Plot
ggplot(produkt_A_data_long, aes(x = Grundlag, y = Value, fill = Attribute)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  labs(title = "Aggregated Values for Different Attributes by Grundlag",
   x = "Grundlag",
   y = "Value") +
  theme_minimal()
```

and I get grouped dodged bar plot.

I know how to change the code so the Attributes get stacked, but how do I get "Bidrag" stacked op top of (or under) "Depot" while "GaranteretYdelse" stays dodged next to the stacked?

Comment: See [ggplot2 - bar plot with both stack and dodge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715635/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-both-stack-and-dodge) for some options.

Comment: Thank you. I already tried that, byt since my x isn't numeric, I can't get it dodged (barwidth + 0.1). I can delete this part, but then the bars are placed in front of each other, making only the one visible

Comment: You could convert your categorical variable to a numeric using e.g. `as.numeric(factor(x))`. Anyway, if you get stuck it would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared using `dput()`, e.g. run `dput(head(produkt_A_data, 10))` and copy & paste the output into your question.