# Create a ggplot with position dodged as well as stacked

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a bar/col plot in ggplot2 where I want the bars to dodge for the treatment (type) and stack for the species (name). I counted small juveniles, large juveniles and adults. The y-axis is for the counts, where I stack the different age classes on top of each other so the bar goes up to the sum of the three. Is there a way for me to give the three boxes each bar consists of a different color to show the age classes?

This is the code I am using:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- expand.grid(name = c("hyalina","copepod","bosmina"),
                  age = c("juvenileS","juvenileL","adult"),
                  type = c("tapwater", "pondwater"))
df$count <- sample(5:200, size = nrow(df), replace = T)

ggplot(df, aes(x = as.numeric(interaction(name,type)), y = count, fill = name)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",color="black") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2, 5),labels=c("tapwater", "pondwater"))
```

This produces this plot:
[example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzja7.png)
where I'd like the black lines to be a different color for every age group, so it looks something like this:
[what I'd like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7saw9.png)

Comment: You can add `color = age` to your aesthetics mapping (`aes(...)`). You will also need to remove `color="black"` from 'geom_bar`.

Comment: Potential duplicate question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715635/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-both-stack-and-dodge

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.numeric(interaction(name,type)), y = count, fill = name, color=age)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2, 5),labels=c("tapwater", "pondwater")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("purple","gold","firebrick")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white")))
```

[image]