# writing R function with ggplot

Tags: r, function, dataframe, ggplot2

I have to plot multiple datasets in the same format, and after copy-pasting the code several times, I decided to write a function.
I understand simple function in R, and managed to write the following:

```
testplot <- function(data, mapping){
output <- ggplot(data) +
  geom_bar(mapping,
           stat="identity", 
             position='stack')
}
p <- testplot(df, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar, fill=type))
```

this works fine, however, my plot is more complicated and requires the "data" argument to go separately into each component:

```
output <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(df1, mapping,
           stat="identity", 
             position='stack')+
geom_errorbar(df1, ...)+
geom+bar(df2, mapping,
...+
geom_errorbar(df2, ...)
```

but when I write the function and try to run it as

```
output <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data, mapping,
           stat="identity", 
             position='stack')
}
p <- testplot(df, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar, fill=type))
```

it gives me an error:

```
Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?
```

Is there a way around it?

EDIT: when I try to include 2 dataframes like this:

```
testplot <- function(data, data2, mapping){
output <- ggplot() +
 geom_bar(data=data, mapping=mapping,
           stat="identity", 
             position='stack',
           width = barwidth)+
geom_bar(data2=data2, mapping=mapping,
           stat="identity", 
             position='stack',
           width = barwidth)
}



p <- testplot(data=df, data2=df2, mapping=aes(x=norms_number, y=coeff.BLDRT, fill=type))
```

it says "Ignoring unknown parameters: data2"

Comment: I'm confused. Which version of `testplot` are you actually running? Where have you defined `df` here? I don't seen how `output ` is related to `p` here.

Comment: `data2` is not a parameter, only `data`, thus your second line should be  `geom_bar(data=data2, mapping = ...`
See the rest of my edit for a full explanation on this.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the first arguments to the `ggplot2` layer functions are reserved for the `mapping` argument, which is from `aes`.
So in your function definition you have a dataframe "data" being implicitly assigned to the `mapping` variable.
To get around this, explicitly assign `data = data` in your function definitions.

for example

```
output <- ggplot() +
 geom_bar(data = data, mapping = mapping,
          stat="identity", 
            position='stack')
}
```

EDIT:

There are many ways to do this and it really depends on how complex you want your function to be. If you are gonna stick to a global aesthetic mapping, then you can leave the mapping in the main ggplot call and assign `data = NULL`, then specify which data frame will be associated with which layer.
Consider the following reproducible example

```
library(ggplot2)
data1 <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(10, 50, 20), v2=rnorm(10,30,5))
data2 <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(10, 100, 20), v2=rnorm(10,50,10))
plot_custom_ggplot <- function(df1, df2, mapping) {
    ggplot(data = NULL, mapping = mapping) +
      geom_point(data = df1, color = "blue") +
      geom_line(data = df2, color = "red")
}

plot_custom_ggplot(data1,data2, aes(x = v1,y = v2))
```

In this example, the mapping variable for each of the `geom_*` layer functions are left blank and instead the mapping is inherited from the main `ggplot` call.

This is usually how each layer function knows what data to use, because generally it is inherited in the main `ggplot` function. Whenever you specify a `data` argument or a `mapping` argument, you are generally overriding the inherited values. Any missing required `aes` mappings are attempted to be found in the main call.

```
library(ggplot2)
data1 <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(10, 50, 20), v2=rnorm(10,30,5))
data2 <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(10, 100, 20), v2=rnorm(10,50,10), z = c("A","B"))
plot_custom_ggplot <- function(df1, df2, mapping) {
    ggplot(data = NULL, mapping = mapping) +
      geom_point(data = df1, color = "blue") +
      geom_line(data = df2, mapping = aes(color = z)) #inherits x and y mapping from main ggplot call.
}

plot_custom_ggplot(data1,data2, aes(x = v1,y = v2))
```

But adding additional aes mappings is risky if you are also specifying `data`. This is because you `data` variable may not always contain the correct columns.

```
plot_custom_ggplot(df1 = data2, df2 = data1, aes(x = v1, y = v2))
#Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'z' not found
#
#the column z is not present in data1 object - 
#R then looked globally for a z object and didnt find anything.
```

I believe it is best practices to use [tidy data](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) when working with ggplot because things become so much easier. There is *usually* no reason to use multiple data frames. Especially if you plan to use one set of mapping for all data frames. A good exception is if you are writing a plotting function for a custom R object, in which you know how it is defined.

Otherwise, consider and compare how these two functions work in this example:

```
data1 <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(20, 50, 20), v2=rnorm(20,30,5), letters= letters[1:20], id = "df1")
data2 <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(20, 100, 20), v2=rnorm(20,50,10), letters = letters[17:26], id = "df2")

set.seed(76)
plot_custom_ggplot2 <- function(df, mapping) {
  ggplot(data = df, mapping = mapping) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",
             position="stack") 
}

plot_custom_ggplot <- function(df1, df2, mapping) {
  ggplot(data = NULL, mapping = mapping) +
    geom_bar(data = df1, stat = "identity",
         position="stack") +
    geom_bar(data = df2, stat = "identity",
         position="stack")
}

plot_custom_ggplot(data1,data2, aes(x = letters,y = v2, fill = id))
plot_custom_ggplot2(rbind(data1,data2), aes(x = letters, y = v2, fill = id))
```

In the first plot, the red bars for q, r, s, and t are hidden behind the blue bars. This is because they are added on top of each other as `layers`. In the second plot, these values actually stack because these values were added together in a single layer rather than two separate ones.

I hope this gives you enough information to write your ggplot function.

Comment: that works in principle but what do I call the second dataframe? I'll edit the post to account for it

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

testplot <- function(df1, df2, mapping){

  a <- ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data = df1, mapping = mapping) +
    geom_point(data = df2, mapping = mapping)

  return(a)

}

mtcars2 <- mtcars / 100 # creating a separate dataframe to provide the function

testplot(mtcars, mtcars2, mapping = aes(x = drat, y = vs))
```

From your example you have "data2=data2" - geom_bar doesn't have an argument 'data2', only data. I got the above to work, so an adaptation for your purposes should work too!

Comment: oh this makes sense! it works with geom_bar, but for some reason doesn't work the same way with geom_errorbar (keeps saying "can't add ggproto object"). Any idea what that means?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducable example? And are you sure that you're adding everything to a ggplot()? (No missing plus sign)

Answer (score 0):

The reason I split my dataframe was because I wanted a grouped and stacked plot, and used this question:
[How to plot a Stacked and grouped bar chart in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597278/how-to-plot-a-stacked-and-grouped-bar-chart-in-ggplot/46597859#46597859)

The mapping has to be different so that they don't end up on top on each other (so it's x=var1, and then x=var1+barwidth)

Anyway, I can make a plot with multiple geom_bar, but it's the subsequent geom_errorbar that doesn't work in a single function. I just added the error bars separately in the end, and maybe I'll look into the other options some other time.

I realise these are already functions so probably not meant to be used this way, and maybe that's why I can't do multiple geom_errorbar in one function. I just wanted my code to be more readable because I had to plot the same thing 12 times, with very minor differences and it was very long. Perhaps there is a more elegant way to do it though.