# How to fill each bar in geom_bar using "dodge"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling on how can I fill the bars in geom_bar, using other variable that I used in "fill" variable.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=df ,width = .9, aes(x = SEM_PRI, y = acum, fill = CLASSI_FIN, group=CLASSI_FIN), color="transparent",position = "dodge",stat="identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:25,labels = labelss,expand = expansion(add = c(.1, .1))) +
  scale_fill_manual("",c("SRAG-COVID","SRAG-não especificada"), values = c("dodgerblue3","gold"))+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal")
```

[image]
I'd like to fill each bar above with the value of the variable `acumobito` with the color black and insert that color in the legend too.

Here is a manual example of what I want (I jus painted the last bar, but I'd like to have this in all bars, the value painted in black is the variable `acumobito`.

[image]
Any hint on how can I do that?

Here is my data:

```
df = data.frame(                SEM_PRI = c(9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
                                                                                   21,22,23,24,25,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10),
                CLASSI_FIN = c("SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID",           
                               "SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID" ,          
                               "SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID" ,          
                               "SRAG-COVID","SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada",
                               "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada",
                               "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada",
                               "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada",
                               "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-não especificada",
                               "SRAG-não especificada", "SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID",           
                               "SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID","SRAG-COVID"),
                acum = c(1,10,29,62,80,105,129,155,183,237,297,380,477,594,665,679,20,40,57,83,99,119,139,160,
                            197,241,355,667,968,1240,1466,1715,1975,2229,2423,2583,2714,2841,2953,3012,3026,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                            0,1),
                acumobito = c(1,2,4,8,11,20,27,29,37,47,53,67,80,89,95,96,1,1,3,4,7,7,9,9,10,11,16,47,86,119,
                              142,186,231,265,289,307,330,354,367,377,379,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1))

colnames(df) = c("SEM_PRI","CLASSI_FIN","acum","acumobito")

labelss = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21",
"22","23","24","25")
```

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597278/how-to-plot-a-stacked-and-grouped-bar-chart-in-ggplot/46597859#46597859

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, one simple way that seems to work would be to overlay the black bars on top of the `geom_bar`.  Overplotting is not always recommended, but it does seem to work in this case.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=df ,width = .9,
      aes(x = SEM_PRI, y = acum, fill = CLASSI_FIN, group=CLASSI_FIN),
      color="transparent",position = "dodge",stat="identity") +
  geom_bar(data=df, width = .9,
      aes(x = SEM_PRI, y=acumobito, fill='blahblah', group=CLASSI_FIN),
      color='transparent', position='dodge', stat='identity') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:25,labels = labels,expand = expansion(add = c(.1, .1))) +
  scale_fill_manual("",c("acumobito", "SRAG-COVID","SRAG-não especificada"),
    values = c("black","dodgerblue3", "gold"))+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal")
```

[image]

Notably, the new `geom_bar` needs to be *after* your original one to ensure the black bars are drawn on top of the original.  Additionally, you need to include `fill="some_text"` within `aes()` in order to make sure the new fill value gets added to the legend.  Note that you don't need to include the actual label text within the `geom_bar` call, since that is defined within `scale_fill_manual`.  Finally, you need to alter `scale_fill_manual` to make sure you select the new bars to be black and also indicate how that should be labeled in the legend.  I should note that the ordering of the legend is not always intuitive, and in this case, the new bar item is before the others.  You can always explicitly define that by using a named vector or a list to specifically assign a particular color or label to a particular legend key.

Comment: I was trying to do this using another idea, but your approach worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, otherwise you are looking at using grouping and stacking at the same time ([note the question linked in the question comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597278/how-to-plot-a-stacked-and-grouped-bar-chart-in-ggplot/46597859#46597859)).  But if the simple solution works, then use that.  Just be very aware that you are overplotting (drawing over top of another geom, which is fine as long as you know that it's happening and if it works!