# Combining both grouped bar chart and stacked bar chart using R Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to combine both stacked bar and grouped bar chart using `plot_ly()`. I came across a few questions but couldn't get the perfect solution for this scenario.

I came across the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597278/how-to-plot-a-stacked-and-grouped-bar-chart-in-ggplot) using `ggplot2`. But I need to implement using `plot_ly`

This is the data frame I am trying to plot

```
structure(list(QuarterYear = c("Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", 
"Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", 
"Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", 
"Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", 
"Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", 
"Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", 
"Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", 
"Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", 
"Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020"), Grade = c("Grade 8", "Grade 8", 
"Grade 8", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 10", "Grade 10", 
"Grade 10", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 8", "Grade 8", 
"Grade 8", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 10", "Grade 10", 
"Grade 10", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 8", "Grade 8", 
"Grade 8", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 10", "Grade 10", 
"Grade 10", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 8", "Grade 8", 
"Grade 8", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 10", "Grade 10", 
"Grade 10", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 11"), Type = c("overallAverage", 
"CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", 
"RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", 
"overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", 
"CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", 
"RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", 
"overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", 
"CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT"), value = c(2.48, 2.21, 
0.27, 3.48, 3.03, 0.45, 4.6, 4, 0.6, 2.8, 2.4, 0.4, 2.54, 2.28, 
0.26, 3.45, 3, 0.45, 4.46, 3.88, 0.58, 3.56, 2.81, 0.75, 2.47, 
2.14, 0.33, 2.96, 2.54, 0.41, 4.1, 3.69, 0.41, 3.44, 2.61, 0.83, 
2, 1.81, 0.19, 2.54, 2.26, 0.28, 4.11, 3.68, 0.43, 2.67, 2.11, 
0.56)), row.names = c(NA, -48L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am aware that we need to define the `barmode` as `stack` for stacked bar and `group` for grouped bar chart. I'm not aware of now to combine these `barmode` in one single plot using `plot_ly`

Can anyone provide a suitable solution in R?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you find and provide an example image of what you are trying to achieve? You could add a link to your question to the image online.

Comment: Would something like this be a solution for you? This is probably the best you could achieve currently with plot_ly: https://medium.com/@moritzkoerber/how-to-plot-a-grouped-stacked-bar-chart-in-plotly-df1685b83460.

Comment: I need a solution in R and not python

Comment: What variables do you want to be the grouping variables? and which are color? and is value the height of the bars?

Comment: The expected output is for each Quarter, I need to group the `Grade` with `Type` as the stack. The `value` represents the value of each stack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222362/discussion-between-brianlang-and-nevedha-ayyanar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the best plot_ly can do:

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(QuarterYear = c("Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", 
                              "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", 
                              "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", 
                              "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", 
                              "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", 
                              "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", 
                              "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", 
                              "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", 
                              "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020"), 
              Grade = c("Grade 8", "Grade 8", 
                        "Grade 8", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 10", "Grade 10", 
                        "Grade 10", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 8", "Grade 8", 
                        "Grade 8", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 10", "Grade 10", 
                        "Grade 10", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 8", "Grade 8", 
                        "Grade 8", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 10", "Grade 10", 
                        "Grade 10", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 8", "Grade 8", 
                        "Grade 8", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 10", "Grade 10", 
                        "Grade 10", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 11"), 
              Type = c("overallAverage", 
                       "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", 
                       "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", 
                       "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", 
                       "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", 
                       "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", 
                       "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", 
                       "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT"), 
              value = c(2.48, 2.21, 
                        0.27, 3.48, 3.03, 0.45, 4.6, 4, 0.6, 2.8, 2.4, 0.4, 2.54, 2.28, 
                        0.26, 3.45, 3, 0.45, 4.46, 3.88, 0.58, 3.56, 2.81, 0.75, 2.47, 
                        2.14, 0.33, 2.96, 2.54, 0.41, 4.1, 3.69, 0.41, 3.44, 2.61, 0.83, 
                        2, 1.81, 0.19, 2.54, 2.26, 0.28, 4.11, 3.68, 0.43, 2.67, 2.11, 
                        0.56))

 
 q4_2019 <- dat %>% filter(QuarterYear == "Q4 2019") %>%
  group_by(Grade) %>% 
  arrange(Grade) %>%
  plot_ly(
   x = ~Type, 
   y = ~value, 
   color= ~Grade,
   colors = 'Reds',
   type = 'bar', 
   legendgroup=~Grade) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "Q4 2019"))
 
 q1_2020 <- dat %>% filter(QuarterYear == "Q1 2020") %>%
  group_by(Grade) %>% 
  arrange(Grade) %>%
  plot_ly(
   x = ~Type, 
   y = ~value, 
   color= ~Grade,
   colors = 'Reds',
   type = 'bar', 
   legendgroup=~Grade, 
   showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "Q1 2020"))
 
 
 q2_2020 <- dat %>% filter(QuarterYear == "Q2 2020") %>%
  group_by(Grade) %>% 
  arrange(Grade) %>%
  plot_ly(
   x = ~Type, 
   y = ~value, 
   color= ~Grade,
   colors = 'Reds',
   type = 'bar', 
   legendgroup=~Grade, 
   showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "Q2 2020"))
 
 q3_2020 <- dat %>% filter(QuarterYear == "Q3 2020") %>%
  group_by(Grade) %>% 
  arrange(Grade) %>%
  plot_ly(
   x = ~Type, 
   y = ~value, 
   color= ~Grade,
   colors = 'Reds',
   type = 'bar',
   legendgroup =~Grade,
   showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "Q3 2020"))
 
subplot(q4_2019, q1_2020, q2_2020, q3_2020, titleX = TRUE, shareY = T) %>%
  layout(barmode = 'stack', showlegend = TRUE)
```

[image: subplots and stacked bars in plot_ly]

Answer (score 1):

The answer above using subplots works, but for my own sake (and perhaps the sake of others) I thought it'd be useful to expand on this using `purrr` for people who have too many "subplots" to bother working with.

```
library(purrr)
subplot(
  map(dat$QuarterYear %>% unique(), function(.x){
    
    purr_data <- dat %>% filter(QuarterYear == .x) %>%
      group_by(Grade) %>% 
      arrange(Grade) 
    
    x_title <- purr_data$QuarterYear %>% unique()  
    show_legend_once = ifelse(x_title == "Q4 2019",TRUE,FALSE)

    plot_ly(data = purr_data, 
      x = ~Type, 
      y = ~value, 
      color= ~Grade,
      colors = 'Reds',
      type = 'bar', 
      legendgroup=~Grade,
      showlegend=show_legend_once
      ) %>% 
    layout(xaxis = list(title = x_title))
 
  })
,titleX = TRUE,shareY = T) %>% layout(barmode = 'stack', showlegend = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have both of your plots and want them to display in one figure you could use the following I guess:

```
fig <- subplot(fig1, fig2)
```