# Bar graph: Combine one stacked bar with one dodged bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to recreate a bar graph found on page 4 of the following [report](https://www.uspsoig.gov/sites/default/files/document-library-files/2020/19BG010FT000-R20.pdf):

[image]

The figure has three bars with the first two stacked and the third dodged next to it. I've seen iterations of this question but none that recreate the figure in this exact way.

Here is the data:

```
a <- rep(c('RHB', 'FERS', 'CSRS'), 3)
b <- c(rep('Assets', 3), rep('Amount Past Due', 3), 
       rep('Actuarial Liability', 3))
c <- c(45.0, 122.5, 152.3, 47.2, 3.4, 4.8, 114.4, 143.4, 181.3)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
names(df) <- c('Fund', 'Condition', 'Value')
```

And what I've managed so far:

```
p <- ggplot(subset_data, aes(fill=Condition, y=Value, x=Fund)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") + 
  coord_flip()
```

I'm not partial to `ggplot` so if there's another tool that works better I'm ok using another package.

Comment: Seems relevant: [ggplot2 - bar plot with both stack and dodge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715635/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-both-stack-and-dodge)

Comment: Also see the approaches here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597278/how-to-plot-a-stacked-and-grouped-bar-chart-in-ggplot  Note if you go with facets you can remove the spacing and move the strip labels to make things look like the bars are in a single panel instead of multiple panels if that's important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking some ideas from the link @aosmith posted.

You can call `geom_bar` twice, once with `Assets` and `Amounts Past Due` stacked, and again with just `Actuarial Liability`.

You can use `width` to make the bars thinner, then nudge one set of bars so the two `geom_bar` calls are not overlapping. I chose to make the width `0.3` and nudge by `0.3` so the edges just line up. If you nudge by more you will see a gap between the two bars.

Edit: add some more formatting and numeric labels

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

df_al  <- filter(df, Condition == 'Actuarial Liability')
df_xal <- filter(df, Condition != 'Actuarial Liability')

bar_width <- 0.3
hjust_lab <- 1.1
hjust_lab_small <- -0.2 # hjust for labels on small bars

ggplot() + 
  theme_classic() +
  geom_bar(data = df_al, 
           aes(fill=Condition, y=Value, x=Fund),
           position = position_nudge(x = -bar_width),
           width = bar_width,
           stat="identity") +
  geom_bar(data = df_xal, 
           aes(fill=Condition, y=Value, x=Fund),
           position="stack", 
           stat="identity",
           width = bar_width) +
  geom_text(data = df_al, 
            aes(label= dollar(Value, drop0trailing = TRUE), y=Value, x=Fund),
            position = position_nudge(x = -bar_width),
            hjust = hjust_lab) +
  geom_text(data = df_xal, 
            aes(label= dollar(Value, drop0trailing = TRUE), y=Value, x=Fund),
            position="stack",
            hjust = ifelse(df_xal$Value < 5, hjust_lab_small,  hjust_lab)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('firebrick3', 'lightsalmon', 'dodgerblue')) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,180, by = 20), labels = dollar) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think I would use the "sneaky facet" method, after adding a dummy variable to dodge the columns and making `Fund` a factor with the correct order:

```r
df$not_liability <-df$Condition != "Actuarial Liability"
df$Fund <- factor(df$Fund, levels = c('RHB', 'FERS', 'CSRS'))
```

Most of the plotting code is then an attempt to copy the look of the supplied plot:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(fill=Condition, y=Value, x=not_liability)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.5, 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:10 * 20, labels = scales::dollar) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(Fund~., switch = "y") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#c00000", "#f7c290", "#0071bf"), name = "") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "points"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length.y = unit(0, "points"),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.text = element_text(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line())
```

[image]