# (Stacked) Barplot with grouping within facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, phyloseq

I would like to create a stacked barplot with groupings within a facet grid.
My Data looks like this:

| Sample | subject | staging | Species | Abundance% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sample1 | 1 | Patch | A | 100 |
| sample2 | 1 | Plaque | B | 50 |
| sample2 | 1 | Plaque | A | 50 |
| sample3 | 1 | nonlesional | C | 100 |
| sample4 | 1 | nonlesional | A | 100 |
| sample5 | 2 | Patch | A | 100 |
| sample6 | 2 | Patch | B | 100 |
| sample7 | 2 | nonlesional | C | 100 |
| sample8 | 2 | nonlesoinal | A | 100 |

I already created [his stacked barplot with facet_grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4EvZ.jpg) using the following code:

```
mdf = read.tsv("XXX.tsv")
p = ggplot(mdf, aes_string(x = "Sample", y = "Abundance", fill = "Species")
p = p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", color = "black")
p = p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0))
p = p + facet_grid(~staging, scales = "free")
p
```

Now I want to reorganize the bars from each sample to the respective subject within the facet_grid to achieve a better overview. E. g., using above example, sample3 and sample4 belong to subject 1 an should be grouped together in the facet "nonlesional" as sample7 and sample8 should be grouped to subject 2 in the same facet.

I tried several times but did not figuere out how to achieve this.

Comment: Use `p = p + facet_grid(~ subject, scales = "free")` ?

Comment: With your code I am getting the groupings you ask for. Apart from the typo in *nonlesoinal* (*oi* for *io* in the last row).

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this forum.

I am looking for a way to goup bars specific to subjects within the respective facets. Bar grouping performed like in this post [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597278/how-to-plot-a-stacked-and-grouped-bar-chart-in-ggplot/46597859#46597859) but with facects included.