# Stacked bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set that looks like this

[image]

I would like to plot a stacked bar chart with X axis being the `Session` column and Y axis as `Absent` and `Present` columns stacked one above another.

I tried the following but didn't work.

```
p <- ggplot(out, aes(Session)) + geom_bar() + geom_bar(aes(weight= Present)) + geom_bar (aes(fill= Absent))
```

How can I create the stacked bar chart in `R` with `ggplot()`

Comment: And your code attempt is where?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please refer to `ggplot` documentation https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/. Please try to make a minimal attempt to solve your issue...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting a stacked bar plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592041/plotting-a-stacked-bar-plot)

Comment: I'm sorry I did try various methods like this `p <- ggplot(out, aes(Session)) + geom_bar() + geom_bar(aes(weight= Present)) + geom_bar (aes(fill= Absent))` but I was not getting it. I thought one who answers it will give a completely new answers. and no point in pasting my non working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The data

I've produced a table using some of your data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~absent, ~present, ~total, ~session,
        15,8,3,'s1',
        12,11,23,'s2',
        12,10,23,'s4',
        14,9,23,'s5',
        18,5,23,'s6',
        17,6,23,'s7')
```

#### Gathering

In terms of producing the chart, first you need to organise your data by calling `gather` so that you can pass the present/absent variable to the `fill` method in `ggplot`.

```
gather(df, key, value, -total, -session)
```

This arranges your data like so:

```
   total session key     value
   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
 1    3. s1      absent    15.
 2   23. s2      absent    12.
 3   23. s4      absent    12.
 4   23. s5      absent    14.
 5   23. s6      absent    18.
 6   23. s7      absent    17.
 7    3. s1      present    8.
 8   23. s2      present   11.
 9   23. s4      present   10.
10   23. s5      present    9.
11   23. s6      present    5.
12   23. s7      present    6.
```

#### Plotting

Then you can call `ggplot` to create a column chart with the following:

```
  ggplot(df, aes(x = session, y = value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = key))
```

[image]